# Operations on Large Python Sets

Tags: python, set

**UPDATE 1**

Both sets contain strings of maximum length 20  and can only take values from 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

**UPDATE 2**

I constructed the sets by reading 2 files from disk using a library called ujson (similar to simplejson) and then converting the returned lists into sets .

---

I am trying to take the difference of 2 sets containing 100 million elements each.

This code executes in 2 minutes:

```
temp = set()                              #O(1)
for i in first_100_million_set:           #O(N)
    temp.add(i)                           #O(1)
```

This code executes in 6 hours:

```
temp = set()                              #O(1)
for i in first_100_million_set:           #O(N)
    if i in second_100_million_set:       #O(1)
        temp.add(i)                       #O(1)
```

All I did was add membership check which , if I am not mistaken is done in O(1)? Where is this massive reduction coming from ?

*I know about set(a) - set(b) , it is practically doing exactly what my second block of code is doing , takes 6 hours to complete as well, I just wanted to write the whole procedure to demonstrate my point of confusion.*

**Do you think there is a better solution for what I am trying to do ?**

Comment: An `O(1)` operation can still take 5 hours.

Comment: The code you show is invalid since `temp` is a dict there.

Comment: @Blender you are right, but this is not the case I think

Comment: @BrenBam my bad. edited my post.

Comment: The fine print often rightfully states amortized O(1) - in sets and dicts key search may approach linear complexity, if many collisions arise on hash "place" calculation. As then alternate subsequent "places" have to be checked for the "in" test you added (as an example).

Comment: `if i in second_100_million_set:` is a array look-up: `O(N)`

Comment: @vyscond no. Set is always `O( log(N) )` or better.

Comment: @karloss if you say so.

Comment: What are the objects in the sets?

Comment: @ayhan So it means Python set can only contain hashable elements, that is the difference from C++ for example. Therefore `O(1)`.

Comment: @karlosss Yes, you cannot add lists for example.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you showed us how these sets were constructed.

Comment: @BrenBam The objects are strings with a maximum length of 20.

Comment: @Karin What difference would that make ? I constructed the sets by reading 2 files from disk using a library called ujson (similar to simplejson) and then converting the returned lists into sets . Both sets contain strings of maximum 20 length and can only take values from 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

Comment: @RetroCode your code looks okay, if it is too slow, then I am afraid you have to implement your own set (with blackjack and hookers, as Bender would say :) ). Maybe Python's set reallocates the hashtable too late or uses a bad hashing function for your case.

Comment: I'm also having trouble reproducing the 6-hour timing (finding the difference of two 100-million-element sets only takes a few seconds on my machine), so I wanted a sanity check that the second set is actually a set and also to get info on what kind of information is in these sets so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Karin do your sets contain strings of maximum length 20 with values from  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  and it finishes in minutes ?

Comment: Youshould definitely add more details on your OS, computer, etc, Python version, and preferably code to *generate* the input.

Comment: Side-note: You claim your code is equivalent to `set(a) - set(b)`, but it's not. Your code produces a `temp` that contains only the elements in *both* `first_100_million_set` and `second_100_million_set` (the intersection), not the elements in `first_100_million_set` that are not in `second_100_million_set` (the difference). To make it equivalent, your second loop's test should be `if i not in second_100_million_set:` (note added `not`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When talking about 100 million element sets, I'd worry about data being evicted from RAM (going to swap/pagefile). A 100M element `set` on Python 3.5 built for a 64 bit processor (which you're using, because you couldn't even create such a `set` in a 32 bit build of Python) uses 4 GB of memory just for the `set` overhead (ignoring the memory used by the objects it contains).

Your code that creates a new `set` without membership testing the second `set` accesses this memory sequentially, so the OS can predict the access patterns and it's likely pulling data into the cache before you need it even if most of the `set` is paged out. The only random access occurs in the building of the second `set` (but conveniently, the objects being inserted are already in cache because you pulled them from the original `set`). So you grow from no random access to maybe 4 GB (plus size of contained objects) worth of memory that is being accessed randomly and *must* not be paged out w/o causing performance problems.

In your second case, the `set` being membership tested is accessed randomly on every test, and it has to load every object in the bucket collision chain with a matching hash (admittedly, with good hash generation, there shouldn't be too many of these matches). But it means the size of your randomly accessed memory went from growing from 0 to 4 GB to growing from 4 to as much as 8 GB (depending on how much overlap exists between the `set`s; again, ignoring the access to the stored objects themselves). I wouldn't be surprised if this pushed you from performing mostly RAM accesses to incurring page faults requiring reads from the page file, which is several orders of magnitude slower than RAM access. Not coincidentally, that code is taking a few orders of magnitude longer to execute.

For the record, the `set` overhead is likely to be a fraction of the cost of the objects stored. The smallest useful objects in Python are `float`s (24 bytes a piece on Python 3.5 x64) though they're poor choices for `set`s due to issues with exact equality testing. `int`s that require less than 30 bits of magnitude are conceivably useful, and eat 28 bytes a piece (add 4 bytes for every full 30 bits required to store the value). So a 100M element set might "only" use 4 GB for the data structure itself, but the values are another 2.6 GB or so minimum; if they're not Python built-in types, user-defined objects, even using `__slots__`, would at least double this (quintuple it if not using `__slots__`), before they even pay the RAM for their attributes. I've got 12 GB of RAM on my machine, and your second use case would cause massive page thrashing on it, while your first case would run just fine for a `set` initialized with `range(100000000)` (though it would cause most of the other processes to page out; Python with two `set`s plus the `int`s shared between them use ~11 GB).

Update: Your data (strings from 1-20 ASCII characters) would use 50-69 bytes each on Python 3.5 x64 (probably a little more including allocator overhead), or 4.65-6.43 GB per `set` (assuming none of the strings are shared, that's 9-13 GB for the raw data). Add the three `set`s involved, and you're looking at up to 25 GB of RAM (you don't pay again for the members of the third `set` since they're shared with the first `set`). I wouldn't try to run your code on any machine with less than 32 GB of RAM.

As for "is there a better solution?" it depends on what you need. If you don't actually need the original `set`s, just the resulting difference, streaming your data would help. For example:

```
with open(file1) as f:
    # Assume one string per line with newlines separating
    myset = set(map(str.rstrip, f))

with open(file2) as f:
    myset.difference_update(map(str.rstrip, f))
```

That would peak at about 10-11 GB of memory, then drop as elements from the second input were removed, leaving you with just the difference `set` and nothing else. Other options include using sorted `list`s of data, which would reduce the overhead from 4 GB per `set` to ~850 MB per `list`, then iterate them both in parallel (but not simultaneously; `zip` is no good here) to find the elements that exist in the first `list` but not the second, removing some of the random access costs too.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if an element is in a set does appear to be O(1), see below code. A set must be internally made with a hash function. The rate of success of hash tables depends on the key's you use, and the way Python guesses what you did. using a `range(n)` for a set is then sort of ideal.

```
import time
def foo(n):
  myset = set(range(n))
  to = time.time()
    for e in myset:     #O(n)
      if e in myset:    #O(n) or O(1)?
        pass
      else:
        raise "Error!"
  print time.time() - to
  return

>>> foo(10**6)
0.0479998588562
>>> foo(10**7)
0.476000070572
```

Thus the function foo executes in O(n) and the check if the element is in the set used O(1) only.